# Angular 2+ Get Age from HTML5 Date Input

Tags: angular, typescript, date

I'm trying to calculate the age from an existing form that uses a HTML5 date input using angular. Preferably without the user having to click anything to generate this.

I'm currently able to grab the date but the format seems to break my code. Is there a way to make this work (change the format) or a new way that is more effective?

Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<input type="date" name="dob" [(ngModel)]="birthdate">
<button (click)="getAge()">Get Age</button>
<input type="text" name="age" [(ngModel)]="data.age">
```

TS:

```
data: any;
birthdate: any;

constructor() {
 this.data = {};
 this.data.age = '';
 this.birthdate = this.birthdate;
}

public getAge() {
 console.log(this.birthdate);
 const timeDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() - this.birthdate);
 console.log(timeDiff);
 this.data.age = Math.floor((timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 365);
 console.log(this.data.age);
}
```

Comment: You can try this: `<button (click)="getAge(birthdate)">Get Age</button>`. And into your component `public getAge(date)`
**PS**: This has no sense `this.birthdate = this.birthdate;`

Answer (score 0):

```
//dob is the date
function getAge(dob)
{
    alert( new Date().getFullYear() - new Date(dob).getFullYear());
}

getAge('11/07/1993');//function call
```

Comment: Hi Kumar, thanks for your the above. This is nice and simple but it does not calculate the age correctly as it does not take months, days, hours into account. How could I go about extending this to account for these?

Comment: function getAge(dateString) 
    {
        var today = new Date();
        var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
        var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
        var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
        if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) 
        {
            age--;
        }
        return age;
    }

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I'm getting 'Invalid Date' in the console at 'var birthDate = new Date(dateString);'

Answer (score 0):

Please note this is the full age, meaning you get something like 26.5131, so convert it how you want..

```
calculateAge(birthDate:Date): number {
    const now = new Date();
    const age = (now - birthDate) / (31556952000); // 31556952000 = 1 year in milliseconds
    return age;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ofek. i'm getting 'The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type' on 'now - birthDate'. How can i fix this?

Comment: change (now - birthDate) to (now.getTime() - birthDate.getTime())

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the HTML5 type="date" input meant that I needed to find a way to format it correctly so I used the following - https://github.com/JohannesHoppe/angular-date-value-accessor

This then meant that my original code above worked. After some more research though to ensure the age was accurate I found out that it was best practice to add '.25' to the Math.floor((timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 365);

Hope this helps anyone else looking to achieve this with Angular 2+

HTML:

```
<input type="date" name="dob" [(ngModel)]="birthdate" useValueAsDate>
<button (click)="getAge()">Get Age</button>
<input type="text" name="age" [(ngModel)]="data.age">
```

TS:

```
  data: any;
  birthdate: any;

  constructor() {
   this.data = {};
   this.data.age = '';
  }

  public getAge() {
   const timeDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() - this.birthdate);
   this.data.age = Math.floor((timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 365.25);
  }
```